# How to disable integrated Windows authentication Internet Explorer in Group Policy Management on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, internet-explorer

I'm wondering if it is possible to disable the integrated Windows authentication of Internet Explorer by using Group Policy Management on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

short question - short answer.

yes.

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Configuring-Advanced-IE-Settings-Using-Group-Policy.html

see the part with title "Enable integrated windows authentication"